# Mapping over data so that it renders on the page newest to oldest

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Editing because I have more relevant information: I am connecting to an api to get a recipe made by having the user input a recipe name and ingredients. The api then answers back with instructions on a recipe based off their input. I have it set up, however I'm trying to map over the data so that the user can keep inputting different recipe names and ingredients. This list should be arranged from newest to oldest. This is the form used to grab the data and the api post call:

```js
export default function RecipeForm() {
  const [recipeInput, setRecipeInput] = useState("");
  const [ingredientsInput, setIngredientsInput] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const [recipeArray, setRecipeArray] = useState([]);

  const data = {
    prompt: `Write a recipe based on the recipe name, ingredients and instructions:Recipe name:\n\n${recipeInput}\n\nIngredients:\n\n${ingredientsInput}\n\nInstructions:`,
    temperature: 0.7,
    max_tokens: 256,
    top_p: 1.0,
  };

  async function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://api/url.com",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_KEY}`,
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then((response) => {
      setResult({
        recipe: recipeInput,
        ingredients: ingredientsInput,
        instructions: response.data.choices[0].text,
      });
      console.log(response.data.choices[0].text);
    });
    setRecipeInput(recipeInput);
    setIngredientsInput(ingredientsInput);
    setRecipeArray(recipeArray.push(result));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <CardContent>
          <TextField
            id="recipeInput"
            label="Enter a recipe name here"
            value={recipeInput}
            onChange={(e) => setRecipeInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <TextField
            id="ingredientsInput"
            label="Enter your ingredients here"
            value={ingredientsInput}
            onChange={(e) => setIngredientsInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Button onClick={submitHandler}>See your recipe!</Button>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>

      {recipeArray.map((recipes) => {
        return (
          <Recipe
            recipeInput={recipes.ecipeInput}
            setRecipeInput={recipes.setRecipeInput}
            ingredientsInput={recipes.ingredientsInput}
            setIngredientsInput={recipes.setIngredientsInput}
            result={recipes.result}
            setResult={recipes.setResult}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'd like to empty the form once the user hits the button, I think since I reshaped how setResults shows it's results, I may be able to empty the setRecipeInput and setIngredints input if I save the usestate as ("").

Currently when I try to map over the data I get an error in the console saying:"Uncaught TypeError: recipeArray.map is not a function". I am guessing it's because the data that I'm trying to get on setResult isn't going through and being turned into an array in order to map through it but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Form' and 'Recipe' component share the same states 'recipeInput' and 'ingredientsInput', so when you empty the form by 'setRecipeInput('')' and 'setIngredientsInput('')' once the user hits the button, the 'Recipe' also gets empty.

Use another two states such as 'recipeSaved' and 'igredientsSaved' for 'Recipe', once the user hits the button, set 'recipeInput' and 'ingredientsInput' values to 'recipeSaved' and 'igredientsSaved', then empty them.

By the way, the 'capitalize' and 'capitalizeAgain' functions in your second code section are the same!

Comment: I will give that a try, the capitalize and capitalize again functions are changing two different inputs to capital. I'm actually not sure if there's a way to combine them so that I have them both doing the same thing in that function, but then separate them when trying to split